# Using a while loops to output data, but it is skipping the first number needed to output. Program is very close to working fine, but doesn't work

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, while-loop

[Problem Sample Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DvUT.png)

[Problem Description (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXrLJ.png)

[Problem Description (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Fju.png)
The link above is an image of what the program should do once reading in a text file and outputting it correctly to another file. The two other links are descriptions of the problem itself. My problem is that while most of the logic works, when it comes to printing it out, it skips the first number in the input file. For example, if the input file was:
1 10000
2 5000
3 150000
Right now the output in the file prints:
Store 2: *
Store 3: ***
Again, the image provides a better example of what is to happen. The code should work for any text file given, no matter for the order of the numbers: (ex: 50 10000, 5 5000, so on).

I am not sure why this happening. I'm attaching my code for reference below. I would like to apologize in advance for the lack of comments right now, I'm trying to fix the error first. I have narrowed the error down to the while loop in the main function however. Second, I'm somewhat of a beginner, so please excuse any silly mistakes I've made or if I did things in a more inefficient way. Another note is that I can't change the signatures for the functions, and I have to check the values if they are valid in the readFile() function. I also cannot use arrays, or the pause command, or break and continue. Third, I am pretty new to stack overflow so please do excuse any errors I make. Thank you!

As of now, the code that is commented out, is code I don't plan to use, but if there is a way to achieve the goal using that code and staying within the guidelines, please do let me know. This error is quite a frustrating one! Also, I do have some more error to fix afterwards, but those are minor ones I can fix later. I want to fix this error first. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool readFile(ifstream&, long long int&, unsigned int&);
void display(ofstream&, long long int, unsigned int);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;
    string fileName;

    long long int salesData;
    unsigned int storeNumber;

    cout << "Enter input file name" << endl;
    cin >> fileName;

    inputFile.open(fileName);

    bool fileRead = readFile(inputFile, salesData, storeNumber);

    if(fileRead)//inputFile >> storeNumber >> salesData)
    {
        outputFile.open("saleschart.txt");
        outputFile << "SALES BAR CHART" << endl;
        outputFile << "(Each * equals 5,000 dollars)" << endl;

        while(inputFile >> storeNumber >> salesData)
        {
            display(outputFile, salesData, storeNumber);
            /*
            if(storeNumber < 1 || storeNumber > 99)
            {
                cout << "The store number " << storeNumber << " is not valid" << endl;
            }
            if(salesData < 0)
            {
                cout << "The sales value for store " << storeNumber << " is negative" << endl;
            }
         */


        }
        inputFile.close();
        outputFile.close();
    }



    return 0;

      /*
       while(inputFile >> storeNumber >> salesData)
       {
           int counter = 1;
           for(int i = 1; i <= counter; i++)
           {
               counter++;
               bool fileRead = readFile(inputFile, salesData, storeNumber);
               if(fileRead)
               {
                   outputFile.open("saleschart.txt");
                   outputFile << "SALES BAR CHART" << endl;
                   outputFile << "(Each * equals 5,000 dollars)" << endl;
                   display(outputFile, salesData, storeNumber);
               }
           }
        */
}


bool readFile(ifstream& inputFile, long long int& salesData, unsigned int& storeNumber)
{
    if(inputFile)
    {
        inputFile >> storeNumber >> salesData;
        if(storeNumber == NULL)
        {
            cout << "The file was empty" << endl;
            return false;
        }
        if(storeNumber < 1 || storeNumber > 99)
            cout << "The store number " << storeNumber << " is not valid" << endl;
        if(salesData < 0)
            cout << "The sales value for store " << storeNumber << " is negative" << endl;
        else
            return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File \"sales.txt\" could not be opened" << endl;
       return false;
    }

    return false;
    /*
    if(inputFile.eof())
        return false;
    else
    {
        inputFile >> storeNumber >> salesData;
        return true;
    }
    */
}


void display(ofstream& outputFile, long long int salesData, unsigned int storeNumber)
{
    outputFile << left << setw(6) << "Store" << right << setw(2) << storeNumber << ": ";
    cout<<storeNumber; //DEBUG
    for(int i = 0; i < (salesData/5000); i++)
    {
        outputFile << left << "*";
    }
    outputFile << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's skipping the first numbers because you read them (and the don't save them) in the function `readFile`. It's got nothing to do with your while loop which is completely correct. But you can't read the same numbers twice, and you have already read the first numbers by the time you get to your while loop.

Not sure what you are expecting from the function `readFile`, it looks like you tried to read the file in a separate function but then abandoned it. If you just delete the `readFile` function your code should work.

OK reading your question again I see that are required to use the `readFile` function. If that is the case then the correct thing to do is delete the current contents of the `readFile` function and move the while loop into the `readFile` function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, in the readFile() function I have to check if the values entered are valid as I did so above. If it's valid (returns true), then I create the output file, and then I proceed with writing the data to the output file. If not, (returns false), then I don't write the headers to output file. If I only have the while loop in the function, how do I check the values inside the function as I have to? I'm guessing I just need one statement in the readFile() function to save the first read values into the variables?

Comment: So let me see if I've understood this right. You have to check all the values in the file are valid, and only if all values are valid then you have to output them to a new file. Is that correct? If so then you have to change your approach. Curently you are reading and writing the value simultaneously. You read the data for one store then you ooutput the data for that store, then you read the next store and so on. But if you think about the requirements above, they require you to read all the stores, check if all the numbers are valid and **only then** write all the values to the output file.

Comment: So you have to abandon this apporach of read and writing simultaneously. Have you readFile routine read all the values, because you are reading multiple stores you will need to use arrays to store all the values, you will also need to keep a count of how amny values you have read. You then pass these arrays to the outputFIle routine which will write all the values. This is a step up in complexity from what you are attempting currently. And maybe this issue about what you should be doing when is what has led you astray in the current code.

Comment: Ok, so unfortunately I can't use arrays, or else I was planning to use it. Basically the logic is that if the first read of values are valid, then I output only the headers ("SALES BAR CHART" etc) at first to the new file. Only if the first read of values are valid, then you output the headers, and then continue reading the rest of the file. Assuming that the rest of the file contains valid values, then you proceed with writing the output to the file. This one is a little confusing unfortunately.

Comment: The images provide a better description of what needs to be done in case you are having trouble understanding what I'm trying to say.

Comment: It would have been helpful to have that information from the start. Anyway comparing your code above with the problem description I don;t understand why you only call your readFile function once, and then you give up and use a while loop in main to do the reading. The problem clearly states that the file reading is to be done in a function.

Comment: `Your main will have a processing loop that will call the read function`. You should do what it says.

Comment: So I have a loop doing the reading in the main function, but now the problem is that it reads the last value twice, and it also only prints out one value to the file. However my debug statement in the display function prints out all the values to cout with the last value repeated. The only thing I've changed is from after the inputFile.open(filename) statement:

Comment: while(readFile(inputFile, salesData, storeNumber))
    {
        outputFile.open("saleschart.txt");
        outputFile << "SALES BAR CHART" << endl;
        outputFile << "(Each * equals 5,000 dollars)" << endl;
        display(outputFile, salesData, storeNumber);
    }

Comment: I realize it is not formatted correctly, but I am unable to format it properly in the comments.

Comment: You should only open the output file once, before the while loop, not inside the while loop. As for the double read of the last item, that's because of the logic error in readfile. You test `if (inputFile)` and then you do the read. That's the wrong order, you do the read first, and you test if it worked afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems, the main is that the `readFile` function reads the first two values, and then you discard the data it has read.

This discarded data will never be written to the output file.

---

Also in the `readFile` function you have the comparison `storeNumber == NULL` which *might* be a check if the input failed, but that's not how to do that.

First of all because C++ doesn't have null values, `NULL` is an old C-compatibility constant for a null *pointer*.

Secondly, you already have the correct check in the loop where you read the remaining data, where you use the whole input expression `inputFile >> storeNumber >> salesData` as the condition.

---

Now to put it all together, you don't need the `readFile` function at all, instead all you need is the reading loop:

```
outputFile.open("saleschart.txt");
if (!outputFile)
{
    // Failed to open the output file
    return 1;
}

inputFile.open(fileName);
while(inputFile >> storeNumber >> salesData)
{
    display(outputFile, salesData, storeNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Instead of using NULL then, how do I check if the input file is empty then?

Comment: @SreyX Keep a counter, initialized to zero and increased in the loop. If it's still zero after the loop, the file was empty.